# how can I do to know how many times the recipient open the email or the number of click?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I'm working on an application in Java EE, one of the features of this application is to send emails using  javamail. 
I must make reporting on items , how can I do to know how many times the recipient open the email or the number of click?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions

Comment: *"how can I do to know how many times the recipient open the email"* You don't, most email clients prioritize user privacy over your tracking.

Comment: An email should not be considered as more than a chunk of text, because many email clients will not display it as more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is called a [Web Beacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon) or tracking pixel.

A tracking pixel is just a small transparent image embedded in the emails you send out. When your recipients open the email, their client (Gmail, Outlook, etc.) will send a request to download the image. This works the same way that your web browser downloads this cat image. Instead of a cat, you should use a small transparent image though.

[image]

You can link the image to your server, like this:

```
<img src="https://your-server.com/email-tracking/USER_TOKEN">
```

Then, on the server side, you could create a resource that would handle these requests. When you receive a `GET` request for `/email-tracking/USER_TOKEN` you could increment the number of times the user with that token has looked at your email.

You should note that this won't always work. If your recipient has turned off images in emails, or turned off HTML in emails altogether, then their client won't send a request.